# Center a Select Element on a Canvas

Tags: html, css, select

I am using a select object on a canvas using absolute position. The canvas takes up the entire screen and is where everything is, so absolute position works for that. I am having trouble properly centering the select element. Everything that I have tried either doesn't do anything because of the absolute position, or it centers the left edge of the slect instead of the middle.

HTML Code:

```
<select id="tree-type">
  <option value="search">Binary Search Tree</option>
  <option value="heap">Binary Heap</option>
</select>
```

CSS Code:

```
#tree-type {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%; /* centers left edge, not middle */
}
```

I am okay with it not using absolute position as long as it is centered properly on the canvas.

Comment: If you want it to remain absolute then add transform: translateX(-50%);